# Where are the security cert files for TLS Client (Golang) on AWS in Docker?

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, docker

I have a go program that uses a TLS docker client like this:

```
endpoint := "tcp://"+hostIP+":2376"
path := os.Getenv("DOCKER_CERT_PATH")
ca := fmt.Sprintf("%s/ca.pem", path)
cert := fmt.Sprintf("%s/cert.pem", path)
key := fmt.Sprintf("%s/key.pem", path)
client, _ := docker.NewTLSClient(endpoint, cert, key, ca)
```

On my Mac I mount the cert files in ~/.docker/machine/certs to /mnt/cert (DOCKER_CERT_PATH), and the 3 needed files are found and used.

This works great locally on my Mac.

When I push this to AWS, it blows up because these pem files aren't in the same place.  Where can I find these 3 files?

Answer (score 0):

[HTTPS client mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/#/client-modes) suggests:

> If found, the client will send its client certificate, so you just need to drop your keys into `~/.docker/{ca,cert,key}.pem`.

So try that path first.

If not, try  and echo that variable. It could be for instance (on AWS) `~/.boot2docker/certs` or `~/.docker/machine/machines/<yourmachine>`